# Differentiation of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definite-integrals

I have a question I'm struggling with for quite a few hours now. For most of you its probably kindergarten mathematics: Can someone please explain exactly why the first-order condition of
$$ 
\max \left\{\frac{1}{1-\beta} \left[ \int_{0}^{N(t)}x_{\nu}(t)^{1 - \beta} d\nu \right]L^{\beta} - w(t)L -  \int_{0}^{N(t)} p_{\nu}(t) x_{\nu}(t)d\nu \right\} 
$$
with respect to $ x_{\nu}(t)$ is $x_{\nu}(t) = Lp_{\nu} (t)^{-\frac{1}{\beta}}$. (I know how the basic differentiation rules but with the integrals I'm no sure why we can "throw them away"... Would be very happy about help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that "the first-order condition of $\max\{f\}$" refers to the equation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$. With that said, we have (using the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule))
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{1}{1-\beta} \left[ \int_{0}^{N}x_{\nu}^{1 - \beta} d\nu \right]L^{\beta} - wL -  \int_{0}^{N} p_{\nu} x_{\nu}d\nu\right] = \\
\frac{1}{1-\beta} \left[\int_{0}^{N} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} x_{\nu}^{1 - \beta} d\nu \right]L^{\beta} - \frac{\partial}{\partial x} wL -  \int_{0}^{N} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}p_{\nu} x_{\nu}d\nu =\\
L^{\beta}\int_{0}^{N} x_{\nu}^{- \beta} d\nu  -  \int_{0}^{N} p_{\nu} d\nu = \\
\int_0^N [L^\beta x_\nu^{- \beta} - p_\nu]d\nu.
$$
So, we are apparently interested in quantities of $x_\nu$ for which $\int_0^N [L^\beta x_\nu^{- \beta} - p_\nu]d\nu = 0$. Now, **we would need more context** to know exactly what is meant by saying that your equation is "the first order condition". However, it is certainly true that if $[L^\beta x_\nu^{- \beta} - p_\nu] = 0$ for all $0 \leq \nu \leq N$, then the integral must be zero. So, setting this quantity to zero guarantees that the first order condition holds, but is not equivalent to the first order condition.

Rearranging this equation yields
$$
[L^\beta x_\nu^{- \beta} - p_\nu] = 0\\
L^\beta x_\nu^{- \beta} = p_\nu\\
x_\nu^{- \beta} = L^{-\beta}p_\nu\\
x_{\nu} = L p_\nu^{-1/\beta}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful! The equation describes the profit maximization problem of a producing firm.